# Sustituir una imagen por otra - Eventos - Javascript - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, imagen, eventos

Tengo un conjunto de imágenes almacenadas en un array y las muestro recorriendo el array con un "foreach".

**Código PHP** de cómo extraigo las imagenes y las muestro:

```
$imagenes = $cabana->getImagenes();
//Recorremos el foreach del array "$imagenes".
$first = true;
foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
    if($first){
        echo "<img id='grande' src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='260' height='260'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        $first = false;
    }else{
        echo "<img class='peque' src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='140' height='140'/ onclick='cambiarImagen(this)'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

Como vemos hay una imagen superior en cuanto a tamaño del resto.

**El problema es el siguiente**: ¿Cómo hago (desde el lado cliente, javascript por ejemplo) para que pulsada una imagen de las de menor tamaño me la reemplace por la imagen principal de mayor tamaño? ¿Al estar en un array las imágenes, cómo sé en qué imagen pincha? Debido a que sólo tengo un evento onClick para todas ellas.

La idea sería algo parecido a esta ilustración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes obtener el atributo src de la imagen que has clicado y sustituir el mismo atributo de la imagen en grande

Comment: ¿Tengo que tener dos divs? Un div=grande para la imagen principal y un div=pequeñas para las imagenes pequeñas. ¿Un ejemplo? ¿Haría falta un evento de click para cada imagen, no?

Comment: De esa imagen yo veo la siguiente estructura: Contenedor general de todo, contenedor de las previsualizaciones y otra de la imagen grande.

No se si puedes usar jquery, pero con javascript igualmente se puede lograr. Crear una función para que cuando hagas clic sobre una imagen del contenedor de las previsualizaciones, puedas ir al contenedor de la imagen grande y sustituir su src

Comment: Esta pregunta sería mucho más efectiva si te olvidaras del PHP que la origina y directamente publicaras el HTML como queda, etiquetando como [tag:javascript]... Hasta donde entendí de tu pregunta, el código PHP es irrelevante.

Comment: El código PHP debe existir porque es desde ahí (del lado servidor) de donde obtengo las imágenes necesarias gracias a una consulta. Con JS y HTML únicamente sería mucho más cómodo pero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>  
     document.getElementById("file").addEventListener('change', cambiarImagen);
           function cambiarImagen(event){
            var file = event.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                document.getElementById("picture").setAttribute('src', event.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
           }
        </script>
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Léete [answer] para aprender a realizar buenas respuestas. Poner solo código sin ningún tipo de explicación puede ser [votada negativamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2882#2882) y pueden eliminar tu respuesta.

Answer (score 6):

Podrías asignar a cada imagen pequeña una función (mediante el atributo `onclick`) a la que le pasarás la palabra reservada `this`. La palabra reservada `this` permite hacer referencia al elemento con el que estás interactuando.

De esta manera, una vez obtengas la ruta de la imagen en la que acabas de hacer clic, se la puedes asignar a la imagen grande.

Ejemplo:

```js
var imagenGrande = document.getElementById("grande");

function cambiarImagen(imagen){
   imagenGrande.src = imagen.src;
}
```

```css
.peque{
   width: 100px;
}

#grande{
   width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img class="peque" src="https://i2.wp.com/medioambienteynaturaleza.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Fondos-de-pantalla-de-paisajes-naturales25.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)">
<img class="peque" src="http://losviajesdedomi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Cano-Cristales-Los-Ochos-1-600x399.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)">
<img class="peque" src="http://www.paisajesbonitos.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/paisajes-bonitos-de-oto%C3%B1o-lago.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)">
<img id="grande" src="http://www.paisajesbonitos.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/paisajes-bonitos-de-oto%C3%B1o-lago.jpg">
```

Aplicado a tu caso simplemente tendrías que añadir la función en tu Javascript y añadirles el atributo `onclick` a cada una de las imágenes cuando las imprimes mediante la sentencia `echo`.

Comment: Funciona en tu ejemplo pero trasladado a mi código me da error. Edito el código de la pregunta. Mira el texto que puse: al tener sólo un onclick para todas las imagenes, ¿cómo sabría en que imagen pincha?

Comment: @omaza1990 Sabes en que imagen pincha porque le pasas la palabra `this` que hace referencia al elemento con el que interactúas en cada momento. Por eso cuando hago `imagen.src` obtengo la URL correspondiente a la imagen en la que estoy pinchando.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. Pues no entiendo porque no me funciona...

Comment: @omaza1990 ¿Podrías indicar cómo estás insertando el JavaScript? ¿Esta en el mismo fichero? Cómo recomendación te diría que separaras en tu pregunta lo original a lo que tienes actualmente. Así se puede seguir mejor la trazabilidad de la misma.

Comment: Está en un archivo externo. Está colocado en el <head> con la siguiente línea de código: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cambiar_imagen.js"></script>

Comment: @omaza1990 Asegúrate de que el fichero se encuentra en esa ruta. Es decir, a la misma altura en la que estés cargando tus imágenes tendrá que haber una carpeta llamada js y dentro de ella un fichero `cambiar_imagen.js`>

Comment: Funciona por fin.

Answer (score 1):

Primero deberías cambiar tu `PHP`, para que quedase mas o menos como este

```
$imagenes = $cabana->getImagenes();
//Recorremos el foreach del array "$imagenes".
$first = true;
foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
    if($first){
        echo "<img id='imggrande' src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='260' height='260'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        $first = false;
    }else{
        echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='140' height='140'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

Date cuenta que solo he añadido un campo ID, a la imagen grande, para luego poder hacer referencia por `jquery` a esa imagen.

Por `JavaScript`, mas concreto con `jquery`, se haría lo siguiente

```
$("document.body").on("click", "img", function(){
     var pulsada = $(this).attr("src");
     $("#imggrande").attr("src", pulsada);
})
```

Lo único que hace este `jquery`, es leer la imagen sobre la que se ha pinchado, cargándola en la variable pulsada y luego modificar el `scr` de la grande con el método `attr` de `jquery`

Comment: `attr("alt")`? no dirás src?